# RTSP streaming of video files to 3gp

Tags: java, streaming, rtsp

One of my friend wants to build a mobile site. He also has a couple of video files that should be streamed on to visitors mobile when chosen. I want to know if there exists a library to stream a video over rtsp in java. I tried this one http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/lab5-kurose-ross.html. But it had too many incomplete code and was giving errors.

Comment: try java bindings to gstreamer: http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/

Comment: can u let me know how to do that?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, it seems that gstreamer alone is not enough to stream over RTSP. But it's easy to deal with RTP (see [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-gstrtpbin.html)), which is the protocol often used by RTSP for actual data transfer. Concerning RTSP, there is separate project based on gstreamer: [gst-rtsp-server](http://people.freedesktop.org/~wtay/). Is't still in beta, but works well. Unfortunately there is no java bindings for it.

Answer (score 1):

VLC has a nice streaming (over RTSP) functionality. Maybe you could look at streaming in VLCj: http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/Streaming

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try Xuggle with this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/rtmp-to-rtsp-re-stream-using-wowza-and.html

Answer (score 0):

RTSP is the negotiation protocol you can use something like [JBoss Netty for tat](http://www.jboss.org/netty). Then you need something to stream the media itself which is done via RTP. You can use [Gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) (which has [Java binding](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/))